# div with fixed positioning and float

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dbg5X/

Is it possible to have the second div to be in a fixed position and to have it float to the right?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating and positioning are two totally different models for arranging stuff on the screen, and they don't mix.

Try putting `right: 10px` on the second div.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have a single element at a fixed position and *float* at the same time because *float* means not having a fixed position.